# Report testing framework for BIRT (JUnit or Cucumber based)

Tags: testing, junit, cucumber, report, birt

We are using BIRT as our report engine. We have a lot of data and reports.

How can we automate testing? Are there special framework for report testing? Is there special framework for BIRT based reports?

I hope to find report testing framework. That is based on JUNit & Cucumber standards.

Comment: Related, unanswered http://www.birt-exchange.org/forum/index.php?/topic/23067-is-there-any-automated-tool-to-test-birt-reports/